# How to automatically test that Ehcache is used in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, testing, ehcache

I started using Ehcache in my Spring Boot project. How can I prove that the Ehcache is being used instead of the default ConcurrentHashMap, which is provided by Spring Boot by default? How can I prove it automatically in the integration tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to validate your spring configuration.

A one time thing regarding Ehcache is to check logs - you should see the information about it being started and configured.

For automated testing, the easiest way is going to be to have the test configured to be injected with the `cacheManager` bean and then making sure it is of the right type.

This should give you the confidence that your setup is correct.